# Bibliography in table of contents goes to another page for one line!

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

Snippet of my code:

```
\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushright}
\textit{Dedication} \\
\end{flushright}
\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

and then

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{apa} %

\bibliography{Bibliography_Masters}
```

My problem: Table of contents takes two page, and the only voice £Bibliography takes one line of a third page!!!! How can I keep it in the second page, or anyway find a way not to go to a third page of table of contents?

Comment: That depends very much on what you are willing to adjust, concerning your layout. You might adjust page margins with `geometry` package, or change the font size. Both can be done locally, just for the ToC, or globally if you want to keep your layout consistent. 
It should also be possible to have a twocolumn ToC with `multicol`.
Sometimes it is even useful to remove one little subsub...subsection which is appearing in the ToC, and put its contents in a different place, thereby reducing the ToC by one line. It's your choice :)

Comment: it's also possible to make one of the toc pages a line longer by adding a line `\addtocontents{toc}{\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}}` in a strategic place in the body.  i'd suggest that it's usually better to make the first page longer rather than the second.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B -- haven't time right now; i'll try tomorrow if someone else hasn't gotten there first.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Enjoy  the concert :-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton How was the concert? :-)

Comment: No need to feel sorry. I forgot about it myself and discovered our comments while going through the unanswered :-)

Answer (score 1):

since it's not clear what document class is being used, i'll simply replicate
the snippet that you provided.

the most reasonable solution here is to increase one page of the
table of contents by a line.  since the bibliography is two pages long,
i suggest that it's better to make the first page longer, especially since
it won't have a page number.  one line is added here to your snippet:

```
\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushright}
\textit{Dedication} \\
\end{flushright}
\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}}
```

of course, that line can be added anywhere convenient, perhaps between the first
and second chapters.  and if `1\baselineskip` isn't quite enough, increase it just
a little, say to `1.2\baselineskip` -- often, there's a small gap between entries
in the toc.